# Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Im receiving the error in the subject line. Im trying to loop through records in a custom object and load them into the Contact object. Here is the code...

```
public list<Contact> contactInsertItem {get;set;}
public list<Contact> contactInsertList {get;set;}

public SalesConnectContactQuickBuildController (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
...
    List<CustomObject1__c> unmatchedContactList = new List<CustomObject1__c>([SELECT field1__c, field2__c, field3__c FROM CustomObject1__c WHERE Id in :tempSet]);

    for(integer i=0; i<unmatchedContactList.size();i++){

            contactInsertItem = new list<Contact>();
            //***error occurs here*** contactInsertItem.field1__c = unmatchedContactList[i].field1__c;
            contactInsertItem.field2__c = unmatchedContactList[i].field2__c;
            contactInsertItem.field3__c = unmatchedContactList[i].field3__c;
            contactInsertItem.field4__c = unmatchedContactList[i].field4__c;
            contactInsertItem.field5__c = unmatchedContactList[i].field5__c;

        contactInsertList.add(contactInsertItem);
    }
...
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Hi @User277, there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Looks like you already got your answer, but for new questions come join the community over there! :) As a reference there are 3k Salesforce questions on SO and nearly 10K on Salesforce Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have declared contactInsertItem to be a list of contacts, but the code with error is trying to treat it as a single contact. You want `contactInsertItem` to be a `Contact`, not `List<Contact>`